# python selenium : selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: line 20

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import  time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.youtube.com")
assert "YouTube" in driver.title

def waiter(browser):
    elements = browser.find_element_by_xpath(filterButton)
    if len(elements) != 0:
        return elements
    return False

search = "//input[@id='masthead-search-term']"
searchButton = "//button[@id='search-btn']"
filterButton = "//button[@class='yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-small yt-uix-button-default filter-button yt-uix-expander-head yt-uix-button-toggled']"
textFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver1: driver.find_element_by_xpath(search))
textFieldElement.clear()
textFieldElement.send_keys("How to iron the clothes")
searchButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver1: driver.find_element_by_xpath(searchButton))
searchButtonElement.click()
filterButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(waiter)
filterButtonElement.clickandWait()
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

I am trying to crawl through the youtube site using the selenium python binding but it gives an error on line 20 of timeout exception error . I think this is due to span tag which is not visible. So please provide me a method how to resolve this problem

> error generated : //  selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
>   Message:  line 20

Answer (score 0):

In general, your XPath expression is very fragile - **don't rely on the layout-oriented classes** like `yt-uix-button-size-small` or `yt-uix-expander-head`. Instead, for instance, rely on the button text which is "Filters".

Instead of using custom wait functions, use [built-in *Expected Conditions*](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.youtube.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

textFieldElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "masthead-search-term")))
textFieldElement.clear()
textFieldElement.send_keys("How to iron the clothes")

searchButtonElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "search-btn")))
searchButtonElement.click()

filterButtonElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[span = 'Filters']")))
filterButtonElement.click()
```

Comment: Or even better, rely only on specific identificators, exclusively made for selenium (if you have control over project's HTML markp), as text any frontend stuff may change.